# mysql query logic in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two mysql tables `memes` and `votes`. Sample data is give below

```
Memes table
```

[image: memes table]

`Votes table`

[image: votes table]

vote = 1 is for `upvote` and vote = 0 is for `downvote`.

I want result something like this

[image: result]

To calculate up and down votes for each record.

Here is my code only for get records from `memes` table.

```
function loadAllMemes($categoryID,$sortby, $page,$perpage)
{
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("memes");
    $this->db->limit($perpage, $page);
    if($categoryID > 0)
    {
        $this->db->where("categoryid",$categoryID);
    }
    if($sortby != "")
    {
        if($sortby == "recently")
        {
            $this->db->order_by("date","DESC");
        }
        else if($sortby == "popular")
        {
            $this->db->order_by("views","DESC");
        }

    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Memes.*, sum(vote) upvote, sum(if(vote = 0, 1, 0)) downvote from memes
join vote on memes.id = memeid 
group by memeid
```

This is not tried out. So kndly excuse if there is any syntax error

NOTE : This is purely in sql. Please do necessary things to convert for codeigneter

Comment: That is the problem actually. I can't convert it into codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

For Mysql you can directly put your condition us sum function and this will result a boolean 0/1 and you can use it your query as below

```
SELECT 
m.*, 
SUM(v.vote = 1) upvotes, /* this equal to SUM(CASE WHEN v.vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) */
SUM(v.vote = 0) downvote
FROM memes m
JOIN vote v ON m.id = v.memeid 
GROUP BY m.id
```

For active record you can write above query as

```
$this->db->select('m.*,SUM(v.vote = 1) upvotes,SUM(v.vote = 0) downvote',FALSE)
        ->from('memes m')
        ->join('vote v','m.id = v.memeid ')
        ->group_by('m.id')
        ->get()
        ->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution would be by using subquery, although, I think join would be more efficient here.

```
SELECT
m.id,
m.title,
m.path,
m.date,
m.categoryid,
m.views,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE vote = '1' AND memeid = m.id) upvotes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE vote = '0' AND memeid = m.id) downvotes
FROM memes m
```